# Type Missmatch when copy/pasting to visible cells only

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy and paste a list into visible cells only. For some reason I'm getting a type miss-match error and I don't understand why. When debugging the error occurs on the third line.

```
Sub Copy_Filtered_Cells()
    Set from = Sheets(Sheet2).Range("I16831:I20610")
    Set too = Application.InputBox("J4:J16821", Type:=8)
    For Each Cell In from
        Cell.Copy
        For Each thing In too
            If thing.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
                thing.PasteSpecial
                Set too = thing.Offset(1).Resize(too.Rows.Count)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: which line (I can guess)?  Do you have Option Explicit at top of module?  If not then please insert.

Comment: @SMeaden I'm not sure how to use option explicit...

Comment: Thanks for editing and saying 3rd line.  Yes, it is completely wrong.  Here is reference page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx .  This code it is malformed.  I wonder how you acquired it?

Comment: @SMeaden I got this code from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/pasting-into-visible-cells-only/ebec7959-60bd-4903-ad8e-391f2f8d8479. Thankyou for the link, I still dont understand why I'm getting the mismatched error.

Comment: As we established the 3rd line is wrong, from the source link that you pasted it is clearer what you want.  I reckon change 3rd line to something like  
    `Set too = Sheets(Sheet2).Range("J4:J16821")`      Inputbox throws a dialog box to the user and allows them to select the range.

Comment: @SMeaden Sadly I still get the type missmatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use Option Explicit at top of module, I am guessing at what you are trying to achieve.  Here is a stab...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Filtered_Cells()
    Dim from As Excel.Range
    Set from = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("I16831:I20610")

    Dim too As Excel.Range
    Set too = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J4:J16821")   'Application.InputBox("J4:J16821", Type:=8)


    Dim Cell As Excel.Range
    For Each Cell In from
        Cell.Copy
        Dim thing As Excel.Range
        For Each thing In too
            If thing.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
                thing.PasteSpecial
                Set too = thing.Offset(1).Resize(too.Rows.Count)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason the "option explicit" part of the code is pasted outside of the sub range...

Comment: yeah, it's like a directive which tells Excel VBA to force typed variable declarations across the whole module.  This forces strongly typed code.  I recommend in general strong typing.  In this case doubly so because you had a `type mismatch` error.

Comment: I couldnt get it to work so I scripted this:

`Sub copypaste()
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
For a = lr To 1 Step -1

If Sheet("Prospects").Cells(a, 13).Value = Sheet("Address 2").Cells(a, 3).Value Then
Sheet("Address 2").Cells(a, 7).Select.Copy
Sheet("Prospects").Cells(a, 10).Paste

End If
Next a
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub` Edit: but now it says "lr" is a variable that is not defined. I cant win XD

Comment: That didn't compile until I changed Sheet to Sheets.  Looks fine otherwise.  Ok, remove Option Explicit if you are not going to declare your variables with Dim ( e.g. `Dim lr as Long` ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113187/discussion-between-s-meaden-and-brayheart).